# SQL. How to join an existing table with the one that has been just generated (DB2)?

Tags: sql, join, db2

I have the following table:

[image]

My task is: ***for each event selected item , report the event id along with the total unit count for all items for that event.***

I tried the following:

```
 SELECT S.ITEMNO,S.EVENTID, S.ROOMID, T.TOTAL                          
 FROM SELECTEDITEM S JOIN                                              
                    (SELECT EVENTID, SUM(UNIT_COUNT) AS TOTAL          
                    FROM SELECTEDITEM                                  
                    GROUP BY EVENTID) AS T                             
                    ON S.ITEMNO=T.ITEMNO;                              
---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------
DSNT408I SQLCODE = -206, ERROR:  T.ITEMNO IS NOT VALID IN THE CONTEXT WHERE IT 
         IS USED
```

Why is it not working? Can I join an existing table with one that has been just generated?

Comment: I've added a answer but unsure if I understood your question completely. I see you do R.eventno, but I don't see any eventno column in the reservation table. And what is the selecteditem table? Is it the generated table your talking about?

Comment: I have made a correction, it was `r.eventid`.

Comment: And what about ITEMNO? You sure you don't need to join on eventID? A join with the same table on the same column doesn't make much sense.

Comment: What is the error message? "*not working*" is not enough.

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name THANKS for reply, the message is `DSNT408I SQLCODE = -206, ERROR:  T.ITEMNO IS NOT VALID IN THE CONTEXT WHERE IT 
         IS USED`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you didn't want

```
SELECT S.ITEMNO,S.EVENTID, S.ROOMID, T.TOTAL                          
  FROM SELECTEDITEM S 
  JOIN (SELECT EVENTID, SUM(UNIT_COUNT) AS TOTAL          
          FROM SELECTEDITEM                                  
         GROUP BY EVENTID) AS T                             
    ON S.EVENTID=T.EVENTID;
```

The problem is that your subselect does not have an `t.ITEMNO` column, so the `ON` clause wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT S.ITEMNO,S.EVENTID, SUM(UNIT_COUNT) as total
FROM SELECTEDITEM S
GROUP BY S.ITEMNO,S.EVENTID
```

Comment: thank you for reply, but i need "total unit count for all items for that event", and only this condition must involve `sum`...this solution does not fully answer the question of the task.

Comment: Try to update your question with the field of the other table and the field you need to sum. So I can understand it better. Where are the itemno and eventno columns in reservation?

Comment: i am sorry for the caused confusion, i have updated my question with the error message detail. thank you